# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "" because "" is null API REST con java spring boot

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, jwt, nullpointerexception

Estoy haciendo una API REST con spring boot. Funciona todo bien pero cuando quiero hacer la autenticacion por JWT obtengo una NullPointerException al usar una dependencia inyectada con autowired en el filtro de jwt.

Es decir, tengo el filtro que se lanza al llegar la request y que tiene que verificar que el token sea correcto. Para ello tengo una clase JWTUtils con algunos metodos para verificar el token, esta clase la inyecto en el filtro con un @Autowired para poder accederla. Cuando se lanza el filtro llega bien hasta la instruccion donde hago un jwt.getValue(token) y ahi me tira la excepcion.

Ya probe un monton de variantes con las anotaciones de component y service y ninguna funciono.
Aclaro tambien que esta modalidad de inyectar el JWTutils para usar sus metodos ya lo hago en otro servicio y en el restcontroller y funciona perfecto. Solo me da error cuando quiero hacer el Autowired dentro del Filtro. Es como si no funcionase o no reconociera la anotacion.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

El codigo de JWTUtils

```
package com.yoprogramo.portfoliopersonal.utils;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class JWTUtil {

    @Value("${security.jwt.secret}")
    private String key;

    @Value("${security.jwt.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Value("${security.jwt.ttlMillis}")
    private long ttlMillis;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(JWTUtil.class);

    /**
     * Create a new token.
     *
     * @param id
     * @param subject
     * @return
     */
    public String create(String id, String subject) {

        // The JWT signature algorithm used to sign the token
        SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

        long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date now = new Date(nowMillis);

        //  sign JWT with our ApiKey secret
        byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key);
        Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());

        //  set the JWT Claims
        JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setId(id).setIssuedAt(now).setSubject(subject).setIssuer(issuer)
                .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey);

        if (ttlMillis >= 0) {
            long expMillis = nowMillis + ttlMillis;
            Date exp = new Date(expMillis);
            builder.setExpiration(exp);
        }

        // Builds the JWT and serializes it to a compact, URL-safe string
        return builder.compact();
    }

    /**
     * Method to validate and read the JWT
     *
     * @param jwt
     * @return
     */
    public String getValue(String jwt) {
        // This line will throw an exception if it is not a signed JWS (as
        // expected)
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key))
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();

        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    /**
     * Method to validate and read the JWT
     *
     * @param jwt
     * @return
     */
    public String getKey(String jwt) {
        // This line will throw an exception if it is not a signed JWS (as
        // expected)
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key))
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();

        return claims.getId();
    }
}
```

El codigo de mi filtro

```
package com.yoprogramo.portfoliopersonal.security;

import com.yoprogramo.portfoliopersonal.utils.JWTUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@Component
public class JWTAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    public JWTUtil jwt;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        System.out.println("*********** filtro de auth: ****\n" + token);

        jwt.getValue(token);

        System.out.println("si paso verifcacion token");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar colocando este codigo al principio del filtro y luego si hacer las comprobaciones del jwt.

Sincermente lo encontre en una pagina y funciono, no tengo muy en claro que hace, por lo que si alguno me da una breve explicacion lo agradecere.

if (jwt == null) {
ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
jwt = webApplicationContext.getBean(JWTUtil.class);
}